# Random walk on N-Rubik cube group is going like sqrt(number of moves) or linear (number of moves) or? "commutative" vs. "free"(like) group pattern?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, random-walks, rubiks-cube

Consider higher (NxNxN) Rubik's cube group, with specific set of generators described below.
What is important - that there are huge COMMUTING subsets of generators.

**Question:** Consider a random walk making "K"-steps on Cayley graph of the N-Rubik's group. What is known about the expected distance from start to K-th position  for such a group ?  (For "K" quite smaller than diameter of the group).

**Sub-question 1:** At least what pattern should we expect - is it growing like sqrt(number of moves) - like standard  $R^d$ case and many commutative groups, or it is more linear like - what happens for free-group and might be expected for randomly chosen elements of any big non-commutive group  ?

**Sub-question 2:** If it is linear, then is it something like (1-1/13)*(number of moves) for 3x3x3 case, where 13 comes from growth rate of Cubik's group - see Derek's Holt answer [MO322877](https://mathoverflow.net/q/322877/10446). Or in the other words how the "growth-rate" is related to the random walk properties ?

---

**Details. Structure of the group. Generators.**

First take a look on that wonderful video for 3x3x3 case: https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.redd.it%2Fimq4s00bgx1a1.gif%3Fformat%3Dmp4%26s%3Dabea9b805f838832ba835c36eeefd2e73fd2eae1 . You can see co-centric circles - and their moves are clearly commutative.

Commutative generators of the group are rotations of the parallel "sheets" - those parallel to one of the faces. See attached picture - we have 4 generators for 4 parallel "sheets", each such generator has order 4. For NxNxN respectively there are N such generators, again each of order 4.
[image]

Cubes have 6 faces - so we there are 6 families of generators above, but, of course, we need only 3 - because those for parallel faces - will duplicate each other.

So we arrived:

**Group:** have 3*N generators, denoted by $F_0,F_1,...,F_{N-1}, R_0,R_1,...,R_{N-1}, D_0,D_1, ... , D_{N-1}$ - 3 subfamilies,  each generator of order 4. Generators within each subfamily commute among themselves.

Remark: explicit permutation describing  examples for small N can be found e.g. here:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/santa23-eda?scriptVersionId=158030054&cellId=26

---

PS

**Why bother?**

Since DeepMind showed that AI methods can tackle effectively complicated combinatorial problems - like GO-game, one may be curious what are the other tasks can be tackled by AI methods. The diameter for N-Rubik cube group  seems still to be unknown. And that open problem seems which might be tackled by AI methods (to some extent), moreover it can be seen like "toy-model". There are many ways how to approach - one I described [here](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/466399), and one of the issues is related to random walks on such groups - understanding its properties would be helpful for AI approaches. Moreover now (January 2024) there is on-going challenge on the Kaggle platform  where participants competing "to estimate diameter" (well, not precisely, but somehow related - see  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461675/10446) and [here](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/464415)). Imho it would be great to exchange the experience between Mathoverflow community and Kaggle community.

Comment: Expectations about sqrt(n_moves) seems were wrong, see some analysis here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/santa23-randomwalk-commutative-groups-z-n-d